# Wrong layout when using OpenLayers plugin

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2

I'm drawing a simple map and I noticed a weird problem. Very briefly: I have a simple shapefile (a region) and the Google Satellite layer of the OpenLayers plugin activated on my map canvas.

On the fly reprojection is on (EPSG: 3857).

I want to create a print layout with the region and, next to this map, another map with an overview of the first map.

All is fine, I blocked both the map, but, when I try to save the layout as image the second map (that with the overview) is shifted and it doesn't correspond to the original view of the map.

The following pictures show what you can see in the map composer and the exported image:

[image: map composer view]

[image: exported layout]

BTW: I noticed the same problem on the 2.4 and on the master version.

Comment: This is an issue that has been discussed a few times on this forum, but I don't know that a plan to address it has been put forth...